# Protect Excel Slicers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel file that I need to give to a client. It currently comprises of one worksheet but could easily have many more. On the sheet there is a graph and a selection of slicers.

The problem I have is that if I hand this over to the client, they'll see the underlying code and possibly not need our services going forward.

How do I protect the sheet/file and only allow them to view data and operate the slices without seeing any of the background workings?

They must not be able to save a copy, access the SQL code or save changes.

Thanks,

JJ

Comment: you'll need a program like lockxls or similar. excel's own protection is laughable

Comment: or write the code in .net a compile it to a *.dll file and import it as an automation add-in

Answer (score 0):

You can bolt down excel with the protection options so that people can't edit objects and can only select non-locked items.  You can also password protect vba and force read-only open of the spreadsheet.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/password-protect-worksheet-or-workbook-elements-HP010078580.aspx

There are lots of protection options available but the best thing you can do is reference a report/webpage with the data on instead of doing a direct db connection.  This will alleviate a lot of security risks whilst also blackboxing your database.

**IMHO**

Only lock your spreadsheet down enough to prevent silly mistakes - combined with your data being a blackbox, they will get a usable spreadsheet and be much happier with you than if they felt you were aggresively trying to withold stuff from them.  They *may* run off with your spreadsheet but the extension of trust to them will help discourage the behaviour and at the end of the day, if someone wants to really harvest your IP, they will do so no matter how many controls you have in place.

Answer (score 0):

you also can try to protect `VBAProject` at the `VBA` window, something like this:

[image: Properties VBA]

and put a password

[image: VBA_Password]

this way the user can manipulate the worksheet without seeing your code, additional to this, block your worksheet like @StephLocke saids.

Your Workbooks can always be vulnerable, but you can lessen the risk to corrupt your code.

PS. My Excel is Spanish but the options are at the same place.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to protect the worksheets and still allow to interact with the slicers (and only the slicers).

1. Set each slicer's properties to not "Locked" by right clicking the slicer and selecting "Size and Properties..." and unsetting the "Locked" property.
2. Protect all other worksheet elements including cells and Pivot Charts in a similar fashion (set their "Locked" property).
3. Finally, protect the worksheet via “Review” -> “Protect Sheet” and select "Use AutoFilter" as the only action in the selection "allow for all users of this worksheet to".

You might also confer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51270643/how-to-protect-a-sheet-but-still-interact-with-pivotcharts-and-slicers).