# How to Protect a sheet but still interact with PivotCharts and Slicers

Tags: excel, pivot-table

So I created a sheet of `PivotCharts` (PivotTables are on another hidden sheet) and want to protect it so that the charts and their layout cannot be affected, however I wish to retain the ability to use their filters and slicers.

After some research, the advice seems to be the [same since 2013](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/663169-protecting-worksheet-but-maintaining-slicer-functionality-usability.html) i.e.

- Right click `PivotChart` and/or `slicer`, select **Size and Properties**
- Under **Format** options open the **Properties** collapsed menu uncheck **Locked**
- Go to **Review** tab and open the **Protect Sheet** window
- Make sure that **Select unlocked cells** and **Use pivot reports** (now **Use PivotTable & PivotChart** in `Excel 2016`) are the only checked options and click **Ok** to protect the sheet.

When you do the above in `Excel 2016` you retain functionality of PivotTables/PivotCharts/slicers **BUT** you can also move resize and delete any of them.

Setting their **Properties** to locked does not allow you to interact with them at all making it an all or nothing situation.

Is it possible I am misunderstanding the **Use PivotTable & PivotChart** option on the **Protect Sheet** prompt? To me that should mean that I can use but not modify them if they are in a locked status; also not checking that option produces the same results.

Even in `Excel 2016` Is the only option to have access to the PivotTables/PivotCharts/slicers functionalities to use VBA as explained in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1091818/allow-selecting-but-not-editing-a-chart-and-slicers-in-a-protected-excel-sheet)?

Comment: If you protect the workbook structure, does that cover the operations you want to avoid?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not; it only protects sheets from being moved around and messed with. I just tested in combination with Protect Sheet and that made no difference